# Knockout Sortable issues with require.js and jquery UI widgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm trying to implement the following:
https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

but it doesn't seem to understand the paths correctly through require. It says its looking for:

"jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable"

"jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable"

"jquery-ui/ui/widgets/droppable"

but those files do not exist in my solution nor do they get included when you download jquery UI. It's only part of the actual jquery-ui.js file, not an individual file to reference. So I'm not sure how to resolve these in require so it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I downloaded the entire jquery ui - apparently I didn't grab it all. Then after I put the draggable, droppable and sortable js files in the correct folder path that require was looking for I was able to get pass those errors.